# Image draggable option not working after cropping removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jcrop

Following is my [PLNKR CODE](http://plnkr.co/edit/0aMdZ9CJ6t5wxLid3LpM?p=preview).

Flow -

1) Click on any of the four images(pink, green, yellow, blue) they get loaded into the red div.

2) Drag the image and click on "Apply Crop" button.

But now I want to remove the cropping option so I clicked on "Remove Crop" button.

Code on **Remove Crop** button click -

```
$("#removeCrop").on("click", function(){
    jcrop_api.release();
});
```

Now the problem is though the cropping release from the div but now the image is no more draggable even though if I clicked on lower images from the tray and also the mouse pointer gets changed.

Let me know what I am doing wrong with the code. I tried to re instantiate the code "draggable" code in `$("#removeCrop").on("click"` but no luck. I created the whole on my own but from here I am unable to guess what I am doing wrong.

**NOTE**- Images are little heavy so it would be better to download the plnkr and replace images with some static images to have a better idea.

**EDIT**- I taken out some jQuery events from `selImg` event but no luck. Recent script - [Changed Script](http://pastebin.com/pp5KWN2B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing the crop, your

```
<img id="inner" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" ...>
```

will change to

```
<img id="inner" ...>
```

and the classes `ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle` are removed. So the `draggable` will not work.

Also after adding the classes to your `inner` again, the `jcrop-tracker` is in front of your `inner`. So actually you can't click your `inner` component.

EDIT:

One dirty solution could be to hide the `jcrop-tracker` after your `release`:

```
$( ".jcrop-tracker" ).hide();
```

And then showing it in the `Apply crop` click event:

```
$( ".jcrop-holder div" ).show();
$( ".jcrop-holder div" ).css('opacity', 0.6);
$( "#wrapper" ).css('opacity', 1);
$( "#content" ).css('opacity', 1);
```

Here is the edited code: [Edited Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/TIQUZwQHvWViTtOT1bNr)

Comment: So how do I fix it ? any help ?

Comment: Just as a suggestion.. is there a way to know about the co ordinates of the image as how much it moved likewise, as I need to crop it at server end..any hint

Comment: There's a `left` and `top` attribute in `style` which has the pixel results of your current picture position (but from bottom right which is (0,0)). You can access it like this:

 $("#inner").css("left");